# in vb.net How to prevent columns width change when populating data into word table

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

in vb.net when I populate data into table inside an existing word document it change the columns width which I already set in the word document

How to prevent columns width change ?

I use the following code:

```
Dim oWord As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Dim oTable As Word.Table
oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = False
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(Application.StartupPath & "\Missed.docx")
oTable = oDoc.Tables.Item(2)
oTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "text here"
oTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text =  "text here"
oTable.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text =  "text here"
oTable.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text =  "text here"
oTable.Cell(1, 5).Range.Text =  "text here"
oDoc.SaveAs("FileName", Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)
oDoc = Nothing
oWord.Application.Quit(False)
oWord = Nothing
```

Comment: Check out `oTable.AllowAutoFit`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help
I tried that before but no luck, what fix my problem was editing my tables in word and disable Automatically resize to fit contents in table
I hope this is the correct solution and it will not come back

Comment: You can record a macro in Word and then insert and format your table as needed (so that the column width does not change). Then you will be able to see what properties to set in your code (all it needs is to translate from VBA into VB.NET which are pretty similar).